# cannot set TextField Property to Rich Text

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the Following setup for my form in an ms-access 2010 adp file:

SQL Database on sqlserver 2008,

A Table foo:

```
create table foo ( id integer primary KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(0,1), name nvarchar, text VARBINARY(max))
```

the form has the following source:

```
select id, name, text from foo
```

And there are 2 Textfield controlls in that form:

- name has controlsource foo.name
- text has controlsource foo.text

i can use my form to insert and update entries into the table foo, everything is fine except i am not able to set the text-field control to rich text, only plain text is allowed.

i get the following error:

> The settings you entered isn't valid for this property.

hwo can i use the rich text option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

for Rich Text Fields one can use either one of those:

- varchar(max)
- nvarchar(max)